# Spring boot - automatically activate profile based on operating system

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Let's say I have a spring profile that is specific to a particular operating system:

```
spring:
  profiles: mac
  cloud:
    zookeeper:
      discovery:
        preferIpAddress: false
        instanceHost: docker.for.mac.localhost
```

Is there some way to automatically enable a spring profile based on the current operating system?

So in my case, I want the above profile to automatically become active if it is on a Darwin os.

Maybe there is some way to do it with system properties? In this case, I want the `mac` profile to be active if `os.name` contains "Darwin"?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the environment variables to determine OS type then you can do it [Programmatically](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles#1-programmatically-via-webapplicationinitializer-interface)

**Programmatically via WebApplicationInitializer Interface**

> In web applications, WebApplicationInitializer can be used to configure the ServletContext programmatically.

> It's also a very handy location to set our active profiles programmatically:

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

   if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("darwin")) {
  servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "mac");
     }
    
  }
}
```

If you don't want to hard code in application or create config class, then I would recommend setting env variables based on OS

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=mac
```

> In the normal Spring way, you can use a spring.profiles.active Environment property to specify which profiles are active

Comment: Yeah I tried this as well. My pull request was declined: `i don’t like the idea of adding too much of that type of thing in the code though, since once it’s there, it’s there. Our run configs can easily be expanded to cover different envs`

Comment: I would recommend setting it as env variable, if you don't want to hard code @NicholasDiPiazza

Comment: is env variable additive? `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=mac` will that overwrite `-Dspring.profiles.active=prof1,prof2` so that the only active profile is `mac`? or will that result in `prof1,prof2,mac`? or will the system property be the only one that takes effect? `prof1,prof2`

Comment: Command like one will take precedence, it will override the env ones, if you want to add more profiles with active one, look at spring.profiles.include @NicholasDiPiazza

Comment: ah - that is what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

something like this would work for you? Of course you should adjust the condition.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(DemoApplication.class);
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("darwin")) {
      app.setAdditionalProfiles("mac");
    }
    app.run(args);
  }

}
```

Comment: you know what, it might... almost seems too simple! yeah the devs on my team said adding that kind of plubming code is not going to fly in code review. so no on that one.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a start shell script in each environment. you could choose active profile.
for example, java -jar yourApplication.jar --spring.profiles.active=mac